# CSS attribute selector with url

Tags: html, css

Is it valid to use below css:

```
.myClass[my-url='page.html']
```

html

```
<ul class="myClass" my-url="page.html"></ul>
```

My doubt here is that can we directly use some html page name as a value.
my-url is an actual attribute on element with value of page.html

Comment: Why would(n't) it be? Have you tried if it works? Have you checked the spec or docs?

Comment: YES, i just did and now i know it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that technically works but instead of using my-url you should use data-my-url to make it pass HTML5 validation (if that matters to you at all).